# How to add ArrayList items to my ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, bluetooth

I want to connect to paired `Bluetooth` devices by clicking on them using two `ListViews`.

One `ListView` should display all paired devices, those items should be clickable and get connected due to a click on the item itsself. Then this item should be displayed in the second `ListView` that shows connected devices.

I had several attempts to this problem but i couldnt manage to get it working. Hope you can help.

Here is my `Fragment`:

EDIT:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {


Button connectButton;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private static final int ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;

private static final String TAG = MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();

ArrayList<String> mPairedDevicesArrayList;
ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesAdapter;
ListView listViewPaired, listViewConnected;

public void initBluetooth(){

    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
    }

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    mPairedDevicesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, parent, false);
    connectButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    listViewPaired = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewPaired);
    listViewConnected = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewConnected);



    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View rootView){

    connectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

                if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){

                    Log.i(TAG, "cancel discovery");
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                }

                Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth start search");
                mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                getPairedDevices();

            }

            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth not activated");
                initBluetooth();
            }

        }
    });  listViewPaired.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {



            listViewConnected.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesAdapter);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "User canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

private void getPairedDevices() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevice.size()>0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice)
        {
            mPairedDevicesArrayList.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());  mPairedDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.fragment_connect);  listViewPaired.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesAdapter);

            Log.i(TAG, "devices in List");

        }
    }

}
```

Here is my Fragment-XML:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Welcome in Fragment!"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Connect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:id="@+id/connectButton" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    tools:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/connectButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/connectButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/connectButton"
    android:id="@+id/listViewPaired" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/connectButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/connectButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/connectButton"
    android:id="@+id/listViewConnected" />
```

Comment: I did not get you, What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to add paired bluetooth devices to a ListView, and connect to them by clicking on the ListView item. Those clicked items should get connected via bluetooth(if in range and visible) and included in the second ListView, so that you see which ones are connected.

Comment: OK, please check my answer and let me know if there are problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` uses a TextView to display each item within it.

See [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

It has a number of constructors that can be used,You can use this constructor to initialize the adapter with you data

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects).
```

And then set it to your `listView`

like this:

```
mPairedDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mPairedDevicesArrayList);
listViewPaired.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesAdapter);
```

and to set an `onClickListener` for `ListView` rows, do that:

```
listViewPaired.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // do you code
    }
}
```

See more details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Comment: And where would I put this? i mean i want to create the view and then create the list after i clicked the button and activated bluetooth.

Comment: you can initialize the `Adapter` and set it to your `ListView` directly after getting the data that you want to display it on the `ListView`

Comment: Ok, so i got the item displayed in my first ListView now, thanks! I will update my code, so you can see where I did my changes. I'll test the setOnItemClickListener next and let you know!

Comment: So, i edited my code. How can i access one list item? Is there an ID that i can call on when i click an item? because i need to be able to communicate to a single list item for the connection and the adding to the connected list. Thanks!